# meaning of the word "on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

It is from this article. Here is the passage:

> **On** its work on the Skripal poisoning, Bellingcat says investigators searched images on several online search engines, contacted former Russian military officers, browsed photos of a military academy yearbook, searched specific terms online, and scoured leaked Russian databases.

Does *on* mean *according to* there?

Comment: It's like 'About its work...',or 'As for its work...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On** is used here to mean **regarding** or **concerning**.

The preposition is commonly used in the same sense in phrases such as:

> On this subject
>
> On this theme
>
> On the issue